# Print DataFrame Name

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python. Currently running 3.5.2.

I would like a function to be able to capture the name of a pandas DataFrame that it has been passed.

Rather than printing the DataFrame contents when I run my function, as my example below does, is there a way to get the DataFrame name (i.e. "df")?

Thanks for any suggestions

```
#### Test Code ####
# Import pandas module
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[10,20,30]})

# Define Function
def test(data):
    print("Dataframe Name is: %s" % data)
    print(data.describe())

# Run Function
test(df)
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `globals()` and search for the object matching the local variable `data`

```
#### Test Code ####
# Import pandas module
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[10,20,30]})

# Define Function
def test(data):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is data][0]
    print("Dataframe Name is: %s" % name)
    print(data.describe())

# Run Function
test(df)
```

The result will be:

```
Dataframe Name is: df
         A     B
count  3.0   3.0
mean   2.0  20.0
std    1.0  10.0
min    1.0  10.0
25%    1.5  15.0
50%    2.0  20.0
75%    2.5  25.0
max    3.0  30.0
```

Comment: Yep. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: if I put this code in a class and in different file then I am getting the list out of index error. any solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

Just name the dataframe as follows, and modify your function.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[10,20,30]})
df.name = 'mydf'

# Define Function
def test(data):
    print("Dataframe Name is: %s" % df.name)
    print(data.describe())

Dataframe Name is: mydf
         A     B
count  3.0   3.0
mean   2.0  20.0
std    1.0  10.0
min    1.0  10.0
25%    1.5  15.0
50%    2.0  20.0
75%    2.5  25.0
max    3.0  30.0
    # Run Function
    test(df)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Really appreciate the reply. In fact, I had seen the solution you proposed on line but it didn't quite meet my needs. The challenge for me was to read the DataFrame name from the function. @sgDysregulation addressed this with their solution above.

Comment: Good to hear @sgDysregulation helped you get the required output with the other solution.